# How to correctly read the control port when Tor is started with `--ControlPort auto --ControlPortWriteToFile <TEMPORARY_PATH>`?

Tags: configuration, client

It is possible to start Tor with the following arguments (or parameters in Tor's config file):

```
--ControlPort auto --ControlPortWriteToFile <TEMPORARY_FILE_PATH>>
```

So Tor [writes](https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/1d18ecbc5f74e8aba8096e9bfd851ff775bbce0d/src/feature/control/control.c#L134) to `<TEMPORARY_FILE_PATH>` file the following:

```
PORT=127.0.0.1:58771
```

and you just read it in your program. This sounds obvious but if I'm not missing something it is not.

So I think the following steps are necessary to read the correct port number:

1. Make sure that `<TEMPORARY_FILE_PATH>` does not exist [to eliminate risk that you read some old value].
2. Start Tor process with the arguments
3. Wait until `<TEMPORARY_FILE_PATH>` file exists [the file may exist but its content may not be flushed just yet now]
4. Repeat

   - Open `<TEMPORARY_FILE_PATH>` file for reading and read a single line (ending with `\n`)
   - When the line starts with `PORT=`, you can parse the port -> success & break from loop.

I'm aware that you can start Tor and just wait few hunder milliseconds, read the file and you'll get *most likely* the correct port number. However, I want to read always the correct port number.

My question is: What is the recommended (and correct) procedure to read the control port number?

Comment: That is a good question. I know that the file modification is date is not a rock-solid solution (some OSs with special setting do not update), but it can be checked. I've added the question to - https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/issues/40386 - http://dkzerogt6z6ybhcj.onion/rocksolid/article-flat.php?id=218&group=rocksolid.shared.tor#218 You might get some answers there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick Mathewson answered the question here: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/issues/40386#note_2735298

> That sounds plausible to me.  I'd suggest adding a step 0: make sure that the path is somewhere randomly generated that only you have write access, to eliminate the risk of somebody else writing to it. (Using `mkstemp` or similar should take care of that part.)
>
> You might also want to monitor the Tor process that you launched, in case it exits for some reason before it can open this port.
>
> If you're writing your program for a unix-like operating system, you might consider using `OwningControllerFd` instead: it provides an easier method to start Tor with a connection to an open control port.
> Hope this helps!

Edit: Upon further research, it seems that one only watch until the Tor control port file exists because what Tor does (implementation detail!) is:

- https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/e247aab4eceeb3920f1667bf5a11d5bc83b950cc/src/feature/control/control.c#L159
- https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/0cf3ab54f6701e37a28a3ad06d4dae1d7a031007/src/lib/fs/files.c#L337

Meaning, Tor creates a temporary file (your specified file with `.tmp` suffix), writes to it and rename to your specified file.